# Simulation of robotic spider with ROS and gazebo

Tags: ros, gazebo-simu

I need to simulate walk of robotic spider in ROS and gazebo. I am able to code srcipts in C++ or python for basic elements like cube or ball for simulation in gazebo but I have no idea how to do it for the spider with six legs. Any suggestion how to do that would be appreciated or at least any book/project/source with similiar problem. 
I have currently the model in inventor and transfering it to URDF doesn't seem to be a problem. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can find a nice simulation of a quadruped spider-like robot in the following repository https://github.com/YunjaeChoi/Reinforment-Implementation-on-a-Quadruped

This is how it looks like in simulation: https://youtu.be/jo47bkJQrjU